# Parser uncommon JSON Output in shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell

I need help to parser this JSON Output

Each object brings me a number from 0 to 20, but each host has to parser deploy_status from the host by id number not from the object number because this JSON is very different for me, i am using shell-script I do have jq

```
 "meta": {
    "total_count": 21,
    "previous": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "next": null,
    "limit": 21
  }
}
"objects": [
         {
        "configuration_id": 61,
        "deploy_error": "",
        "deploy_progress": 100,
        "deploy_status": "deploy_succeeded",
        "id": 61,
        "last_reported": "2016-09-02T11:41:37",
        "last_updated": "2016-09-02T11:21:38",
        "maintenance_mode": false,
        "max_audio_calls": 99,
        "max_full_hd_calls": 4,
        "max_hd_calls": 8,
        "max_sd_calls": 18,
        "media_load": 0,
        "name": "host1",
        "resource_uri": "/api/admin/status/v1/worker_vm/61/",
        "system_location": "Customer-host",
        "upgrade_status": "IDLE",
        "version": "12 (29682.0.0)"
      },
      {
        "configuration_id": 62,
        "deploy_error": "",
        "deploy_progress": 100,
        "deploy_status": "deploy_succeeded",
        "id": 62,
        "last_reported": "2016-09-01T16:02:44",
        "last_updated": null,
        "maintenance_mode": false,
        "max_audio_calls": 0,
        "max_full_hd_calls": 0,
        "max_hd_calls": 0,
        "max_sd_calls": 0,
        "media_load": 0,
        "name": "host3",
        "resource_uri": "/api/admin/status/v1/worker_vm/62/",
        "system_location": "customer-host",
        "upgrade_status": "IDLE",
        "version": "11.1 (26965.0.0)"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: `jq ".objects | map(select(.id == $id)) | .[].deploy_status"`

Comment: Hi, that is Great but it was given "syntax error near unexpected token `select'"

Comment: jq ".objects" | jq "map(select(.id == $id))" | jq  ".[].deploy_status"" 
Worked as a Charm
Could you repost as answer for you to have achieve points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works as a Charm! 
Thanks Phylogenesis.

```
jq ".objects" | jq "map(select(.id == $id))" | jq ".[].deploy_status"
```